# How to understand the cardinality of Yoneda in the case of unit?

Tags: haskell

Note that this isn't strictly a haskell question, but that's where I've been playing around with this and where I've seen the yoneda lemma expressed most cleanly...

So, with the yoneda lemma, we know that

```
forall x . (a -> x) -> f x ~= f a
```

But what I'm wondering is, how does this work for the type x when it is of lower cardinality than a? For example, unit...taking f=Identity, a=Integer, x=Unit we get something like

```
(Integer -> ()) -> Indentity () ~= Identity Int
```

Which seems to make no sense?

I've always thought of yoneda in the terms of, say, a=Bool and x=Int

```
(Bool -> Integer) -> Identity Integer ~= Identity Bool
```

Where in a sense, Identity Integer "seems" larger than Identity Bool, but given the fact that it had to have been built by a Bool->Integer, we know that there are in fact only two options...but I feel like flipping it shows that said understanding is not quite right.

I'd appreciate any help understanding this!

Comment: Write it `(∀ x . (a -> x) -> f x) ~= f a` and it's obvious.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Why? I don't find that phrasing any more obvious. You've just changed `forall` to `∀`, right? I don't see what makes that clearer.

Comment: @amalloy that's not what I meant, it's the parentheses that make things clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't fix `x ~ ()`. For the identity to hold, the function must work for *every* choice of `x`, not just a single specific choice. That's why there's a `forall` on that parameter. So let's recast your example, remaining parametric over `x`. I give you a function of the following type

```
(Integer -> x) -> Identity x
```

promising that it works for any `x` that you choose. The only way I could possibly implement this function is to have an `Integer` in my hand already, and call the function you give me on it, yielding an `x`. Thus, my function is equivalent to an `Identity Integer`.

Likewise we can take `a ~ Bool, f ~ []`, yielding

```
(Bool -> x) -> [x]
```

The only way I can implement this is if I have a `[Bool]` lying around, and call your function with each of my `Bool`s.

Since `x` must be polymorphic, it has no particular cardinality, and so the question of being smaller or larger than `a` does not arise.

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it. The guarantee isn't that F b ~= F a, it's the natural isomorphisms from (a->b)->F b...which is basically just means there's an isomorphism per value of a, I think. Thank you!